# Use OR `||` between two string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want use or between two string as `or`, but it don't work for me, What do i do?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/NP8E3/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="DA">
<input type="checkbox" id="DE">

$('#DA'+ OR +'#DE').live('click', function () {
    alert('ok');
})​
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to use a comma instead: `$('#DA, #DE')`. This is the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) syntax.

That said, `.live()` is deprecated and you should look into switching to the delegated form of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) at the first opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `comma` in the selector:

```
$('#DA, #DE').live('click', function () {
    alert('ok');
})
```